# How to share class object between groovy test steps?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have an external groovy file containing all common functions required to automate my web service testing. I reference those common functions by creating an instance of the Class defined within the external file. Now I have a situation to create an instance of the Class in first groovy test step and to use the same instance in other groovy test steps within my test case.

```
import groovy.lang.Binding
import groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine

def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)

// location of script file is relative to SOAPUI project file.
String scriptPath = groovyUtils.projectPath + "\\Scripts\\"

// Create Groovy Script Engine to run the script.
GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine(scriptPath)

// Load the Groovy Script file 
externalScript = gse.loadScriptByName("CustomerQuotes.groovy")
def cq = externalScript.newInstance(context: context, log: log, testRunner: testRunner)
```

How do I achieve this? I need the reference of cq object in other groovy test steps to call the remaining common functions available within my external grooy file? Please help.

Comment: Where do you need that object? At the same test case? test suite? project level?

Comment: @Rao At same test suite

Comment: But where is the above groovy script step located? I mean you have to keep it a test case though it is not the natural fit. Isn't it?

Comment: @Rao that groovy script is in external file as I need the functions to be accessed from all test cases and test steps

Comment: My question is not that. It is about test step with above code.

Comment: @Rao the above code is placed in a groovy test step

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163677/discussion-between-rao-and-srinivasan-ramu).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your question, the mentioned groovy script test step is placed in an arbitrary test case though it is not a natural fit.

The natural fit for the above script is to use `Load Script` which is at project level.

In the script, which is mentioned in the question, change below statements

From:

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)

// location of script file is relative to SOAPUI project file.
String scriptPath = groovyUtils.projectPath + "\\Scripts\\"
```

To:

```
def projectPath = new File(project.path).parent.toString()
String scriptPath = "${projectPath}/Scripts"
```

- And keep the rest of the script same.
- Place the script (after the above change) at Project level's `Load Script`.
- Remove the groovy script test step from wherever it is because of the above mentioned reason.

At the end of the script, add the below statement. Basically *using the groovy's Meta Programming feature to store the object for sharing*.

```
project.metaClass.myObject = cq
```

**Next step:** How to re-use the object (which is the main question)?
Since, your object `cq` is added to `project` object, the same can be accessed in any of the groovy script test steps (at any suite or case) using below statement:

```
def cq = context.testCase.testSuite.project.myObject
//Now call the other methods using cq.method(arguments)
```

**EDIT:** It appears that the above solution works for simple/Primitive data types.

However, you have a class instance. For that some more changes are required.

Here is your complete Project level `Load Script` (includes your code snippet)

```
def projectPath = new File(project.path).parent.toString()
String scriptPath = "${projectPath}/Scripts"
GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine(scriptPath)
def externalScript = gse.loadScriptByName("CustomerQuotes.groovy")
project.metaClass.myObject { 
    externalScript.newInstance(context: it, log: log, testRunner: it.testRunner)    
}
```

And the script for *Groovy Script test step* in different test cases is as follows i.e., just calling the methods of your `CustomerQuotes.groovy` class.

```
def obj = context.testCase.testSuite.project.myObject(context)
obj.run()
```

Assuming that there is a method in the groovy file called `run`. Of course, you can use your own method.

**EDIT 2:**

There is another alternative approach too. You need to compile the groovy classes, create jar, copy it under `SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext` directory. Of course, soapui tool needs to be restarted after that.

Now you can create instance and make the desired call to the methods as needed in any of the groovy script test steps.

Comment: Srinivasan, Please use the `EDIT` section.

Comment: I get an error groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException. No such property: project for class at line def projectPath = new File(project.path).parent.toString()

Comment: @SrinivasanRamu, would you please show the screen shot where the script is placed just to make sure it did not put in the wrong place. Here is the screen shot in case if you find difficult to locate ( go to Load Script tab) https://www.soapui.org/soapui-projects/soapui-project-window.html

Comment: By the way, you can join the chat link that we used earlier if you want - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163677/discussion-between-rao-and-srinivasan-ramu

Comment: Hi sir. Could you please come to the chat window?